# Ethereum code to split money in half and store half in the contract and send the other half to an address

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to create a ethereum smart contract that splits the money in half and send half the money to a contract and sends the other half to a address. Below is the code I have. I would much appreciate your help!

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Forwarder {
  address admin;
  uint fee = 10;

  constructor() public {
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

  function splitFunds(address _b) public payable {
    admin.transfer(msg.value * fee / 100);
    _b.transfer(msg.value - (msg.value * fee / 100));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And how exactly is "half" reflected in your code???

Comment: @goodvibration I don't have the half part represented in my code. That is what I need help representing. I would appreciate your help

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov My question is what do I need to adjust in my code to meet all of the requirements of the statement.

Comment: You need to change value of `fee` from `10` to `50`.